# extracting raw images of Flickr URL by python coding

Tags: html, python-3.x, image, deep-learning

I have a dataset which consists of URL of the images in Flickr. For deep-learning  applications I need the raw images. So I need a code in python to extract the raw images from the relevant Flickr page.
A sample [link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/7563597@N08/1378219626)

But the images are corrupted. I would appreciated so much if anyone could help me

When I go to flickr page and want to download image manually, the description of each image shows this sentences:

> The owner has disabled downloading of their photos

Also I tried the code that provide in same topics in python but it didn't worked, again but other errors happen

```
import os
import requests
df4.pid = df4.pid.astype(str)
df4.index = range(len(df4.index))
directory="E://MsSoftware/972/thesis/data set/data"
for i in range(len(df4)):
    r = requests.get(df4['url'][i], stream = True)
     with open(directory+df4['pid'][i]+".jpg", 'wb') as f:
                f.write(r.content)
```

I expect to download the raw images of flickr but the actual output is the corrupted images that couldn't open.

Comment: Please consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on creating an example that SO contributors can easily reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your code.
This, for example, works perfectly on MacOS 10.13:

```
import os

import requests


def download(url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    with open(os.path.basename(url), 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r.content)


download('https://live.staticflickr.com/1076/1378219626_9bc9a789fa.jpg')
```

It produces this result:

```
$ F=Desktop/1378219626_9bc9a789fa.jpg; identify $F; shasum -a 224 < $F
Desktop/1378219626_9bc9a789fa.jpg JPEG 360x262 360x262+0+0 8-bit sRGB 43022B 0.000u 0:00.000
b30521e5ae379eda34d1cad25f4eec5791b2cbc059f03d89dc1ac1b3  -
```

Comment: same as previous code, this code downloaded the image but when i want to open image,the windows gives this error: it is corrupted or didnt support. i couldnt open the image